# Use two network adapters (one for internet and one for lan traffic) on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, routing, static-routes

I have two network adarpters:

Adapter1 : `Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller` ip:`10.0.3.27`

Adapter2 : `Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card` ip: `192.168.2.39`

Both newtwork adapter has internet access. Without any configuration Adapter1 is used to communicate over the lan and internet.

I want to use the Adapter1 to communicate only over my lan network, and my Adapter2 to communicate over internet network.

Some people say that I'have to use the `route` command to alter route table, but is not clear for me what entries I have to delete and what (static route?!?) I have to add.

This is my route table obtained with `route print` command:

```
  ===========================================================================
  Elenco interfacce
   13...0c ee e6 9c 24 2e ......Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card
   22...0c ee e6 9c 24 2e ......Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
   20...00 05 9a 3c 78 00 ......Cisco Systems VPN Adapter for 64-bit Windows
   11...00 24 e8 ec c9 51 ......Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
    1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
   24...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
  ===========================================================================

  IPv4 Tabella route
  ===========================================================================
  Route attive:
       Indirizzo rete             Mask          Gateway     Interfaccia Metrica
            0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         10.0.3.1        10.0.3.27     10
            0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.2.1     192.168.2.39     25
           10.0.3.0    255.255.255.0         On-link         10.0.3.27    266
          10.0.3.27  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.0.3.27    266
         10.0.3.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.0.3.27    266
          127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
          127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
    127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        169.254.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link    169.254.230.75    276
     169.254.230.75  255.255.255.255         On-link    169.254.230.75    276
    169.254.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    169.254.230.75    276
        192.168.2.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.2.39    281
       192.168.2.39  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.2.39    281
      192.168.2.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.2.39    281
          224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
          224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    169.254.230.75    276
          224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.2.39    281
          224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         10.0.3.27    266
    255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
    255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    169.254.230.75    276
    255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.2.39    281
    255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.0.3.27    266
  ===========================================================================
  Route permanenti:
    Nessuna

  IPv6 Tabella route
  ===========================================================================
  Route attive:
   Interf Metrica Rete Destinazione      Gateway
    1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
   20    276 fe80::/64                On-link
   20    276 fe80::2d03:d120:4de1:e64b/128
                                      On-link
    1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
   20    276 ff00::/8                 On-link
  ===========================================================================
  Route permanenti:
    Nessuna
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is

```
        0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         10.0.3.1        10.0.3.27     10
        0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.2.1     192.168.2.39     25
```

This means all traffic that isn't handled by another route gets routed to both gateways, the lower metric first, in this case 10.0.3.1.

To route all traffic through your 192.168.2.1 gateway, open a command prompt as administrator and run

```
route delete 0.0.0.0
route add 0.0.0.0 MASK 0.0.0.0 192.168.2.1 IF 13
```